# How long do minecrawler mandibles/bloodfly stingers affect player

Tags: gothic-2

If a player uses minecrawler mandibles it will completely restore his mana. The same is true for bloodfly stinger (after you learn how to get the secretion from it). But both of them work for specific number of times only. So how many you can actually use before they are rendered useless? And is there any kind of cooldown period after which you can start using them again?